# why jquery works on onClick but not on ontouchstart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

why jquery works on onClick but not on ontouchstart?

my html

```
<a href="/list-sky/"
           ontouchstart="startTouch('MICHELIN')" 
           onclick="startTouch('MICHELIN')">                     
     <h2>MICHELIN</h2>
</a>
```

here is my javascript

```
function startTouch(q) {
 // Process the event

 $("#searchRess").load("teste.php?q="+q);
}
```

when i click on it with the mouse it **runs normaly,** but when click with a toucscreen device like a smartphone it trigers the function but not load the php query to the **#searchRess**

Comment: Well, just going off of the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ontouchstart , it looks like the attribute ontouchstart doesn't have a lot of mobile browser support.

Answer (score 0):

The following HTML passes the touch event to the javascript just fine on mobile chrome.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
    function test() {
      console.log("test");
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p ontouchstart="test()">Touch here</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think your problem is somewhere else. teste.php may be a misspelling?

It's also possible that your mobile browser doesn't like ontouchstart. If you're already using Jquery, I'd suggest you attach touch event handlers from the script itself, instead of the inline html.

```
$("p").bind('touchstart click', test);
```

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your anwswer, but my function passes the event on mobile too, i tried with a console.log and it works, but the `$("#searchRess").load("teste.php?q="+q);` only work on pc browser

Comment: Oh ok. Then it's got to be something wrong with the load call right? Again, I don't know what your test system looks like here... Are you remote debugging an android phone connected via adb? Can you get the console error readout, or check the network tab for dropped php calls?